# El uso del con + infinitivo

Tags: gramática

> **Con** comer menos, adelgazas

La frase de arriba tiene el sentido de:

> Si comes menos, adelgazas.

Me gustaría saber cuando se usa la expresión con + infinitivo.

Comment: Nunca he visto una frase así.  Pero esto sí funciona: *Comiendo menos, adelgazarás.* O *Comer menos adelgaza.*

Answer (score 3):

Para que "con" + infinitivo sea condicional, en general se agrega "sólo". La condición tiene un significado modal y restrictivo:

- **Con sólo comer menos** (= sólo comiendo menos), no adelgazas. También debes hacer ejercicio físico.
- **Con sólo mirarlo** (=sólo mirándolo), me doy cuenta de que está enojado.
- **Con sólo tocar algo** (=sólo tocando algo), Midas lo convertía en oro.

"con" + infinitivo puede usarse sin "sólo", por ejemplo:

- **Con mirar** no basta / No basta **con mirar**. Hay que actuar.

La oración "Con comer menos, adelgazas" puede ser correcta, pero sería mejor con "sólo":

- Es muy fácil: **con sólo comer menos**, adelgazas.

Comment: Con preguntar, ¡se aprende!